# Is there a better way to conditionally add a user to a group with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that provisions a host for use with Rails/rvm/passenger. I'd like to add use the same playbook to setup both test and production.

In testing, the user to add to the `rvm` group is `jenkins`. The one in production is `passenger`. My playbook excerpt below does this based on the `inventory_hostname` parameter.

It seems like adding a new `user:/when:` block in the playbook for every testing or production host is the wrong way to go here. Should I be using an Ansible `role` for this?
Thanks

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
...
  tasks:

  - name: add jenkins user to rvm group when on testing
    user: name={{ item }}
        shell=/bin/bash
        groups=rvm
        append=yes
    with_items:
        - jenkins
    when: "'bob.mydomain' in inventory_hostname"

  - name: add passenger user to rvm group when on rails production
    user: name={{ item }}
        shell=/bin/bash
        groups=rvm
        append=yes
    with_items:
        - passenger
    when: "'alice.mydomain' in inventory_hostname"
```

Comment: You can set host or group-specific variables and then just expand the variable where you have `{{item}}`, no `with_items` or `when` needed. Or determine it dynamically and `set_fact`. But we'd need more info on how you determine what's prod and what's test. Also, the answer to "should I use a role" is almost always yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an inventory file called `inventories/testing`

```
[web]
alice.mydomain

[testing:children]
web
```

This will control what hosts are targeted when you run your playbook against your `testing` environment.

Create another file called `group_vars/testing`

```
rvm_user: jenkins
```

This file will keep all variables required for running a playbook against the `testing` environment. Your `production` file should have the same variables, but with different values.

Finally in your playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
...
  tasks:

  - name: add user to rvm group
    user:
      name:   "{{ rvm_user }}"
      shell:  "/bin/bash"
      groups: rvm
      append: yes
```

Now, when you want to run your playbook, you execute it like so:

`ansible-playbook -i inventories/testing site.yml`

Ansible will do the right thing, and look for a `testing` file in group_vars and read variables from there. It will ignore variables in a file or folder not named after your environment with the exception of a file called `all` which is intended to be for common variables across playbooks.

Good luck - Ansible is an amazing tool :)